# Create an Apex class that returns contacts based on incoming parameters

Tags: apex, class, trailhead

[image]

why is this problem appearing ? when both are contact field then both should  have name field.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It'd be better if you were to include the actual text of your code and error message here rather than sharing it via a screenshot. Text is more accessible, and doesn't require people to go to another site to be able to try to figure out what the issue you're facing is. You can [edit] your question to make that change.

Answer (score 1):

The `Name` field is a compound field, which is a combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`. It cannot be written, only read.

```
public class ContactSearch {
    public static list<Contact> searchForContacts(string lastname, string b)
    {
        // list<Contact> c = new list<Contact>();

        /* 
        // None of this work is necessary here:
        for(Contact con :[Select Id,Name from Contact where LastName =: lastname AND MailingPostalCode =:b])
        {
            c[0].Id = con.Id;
            c[0].Name = con.Name;
        }
        */

        // this query will return a list of results, or an empty list. No need to iterate and build another list.

        return [Select Id,Name from Contact where LastName =: lastname AND MailingPostalCode =:b];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually a bit more than FirstName and LastName. [Object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) says FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix (up to 121 characters). Classifying it as a compound field is debatable, but I don't care to be _that_ pedantic (and for pretty much all intents and purposes, it is a compound field.)

Comment: @DerekF And Middle Name, if enabled :p

Comment: You guys are killin' me...